# Input onClick works on Chrome, FF, IE but not Safari, BUT does work on Safari locally?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I thought I had a pretty simple input onclick and script to play a random audio file.

Everything works locally on my system without a problem. Online the code is working on Chrome, Firefox and IE but not Safari. As it works locally on Safari, I'm struggling to find the issue and wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction? There are no error's logged in Safari's Web Inspector either!

```
<input class="btn btn-primary showPointer" type="button" onclick="getRandomSounds()" value="Play A Clip" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var sounds = new Array();
  sounds[0] = "example.mp3";
  sounds[1] = "example1.mp3";

  function getRandomSounds() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length);
    document.getElementById("ashboxplayer").src=sounds[randomNum];
  }
</script>
```

The array has been shortened somewhat for this example but there are 80 objects in the array.

Thanks in advance for any light anybody can shed!

Cheers

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_".

Comment: try using onfocus instead, might work, didnt test

Comment: Tried onfocus, no luck...

Comment: @Teemu nothing happens after clicking the button in Safari! (It's fine in Chrome, FF, IE and works fine on Safari locally). You can see for yourself here: www.ashgould.com (it's the 'ashbox')

Comment: What doesn't work? What if you change the function to `console.log` or `alert` something? Is the problem with playing the sound or is it really with the click event? What happens if you set the `src` of the `<audio>` element with HTML instead of JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Safari have content blockers and auto-play blockers. Once disabled for the website, everything is functioning correctly.

Thanks everyone for their assistance!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <input class="btn btn-primary showPointer" type="button" id="randombtn"  value="Play A Clip" />
     var sounds = new Array();
      sounds[0] = "example.mp3";
      sounds[1] = "example1.mp3";
    $('#randombtn).on('click',function(){
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length);
        document.getElementById("ashboxplayer").src=sounds[randomNum];

    });
```